# Рамка в CSS

Tags: css

Нужно сделать так как на фотке,,ну типо полурамки..спасибо большое

[image: photo]

Comment: Уважаемый ТС, будут вопросы такого рода, пожалуйства продолжайте в этой теме, отредактировав вопрос. Не превращайте стену на главной в хлам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<style type="text/css">
#frame { border-top: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000; padding: 5px 10px; }
</style>
<div id="frame">FRAME</div>
```

Это вообще самые основы!